# datepicker pops out automatically upon loading in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

guys i know it is dummy question but i spent 2 days searching for solution but never reached so plz help me ... i am using jqgrid .. and a column named "From Date" is required to be all the time in editmode .. but the datepicker pops out automatically and i want it to pop out upon click on the field .. here is my code

```js
 <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a Boostrap  and jqGrid Bootstrap CSS siles-->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="resources/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
 

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                data: data.rows,
                //url: "data.json",
                datatype: "local",
                styleUI : "Bootstrap",
                colModel: [
                           { label: 'Order ID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75, hidden:true },                   
                           { label: 'From Date', name: 'FromDate', width: 150,id: "datepicker",
                            editable: true,
                               edittype:"text",
                               editoptions: {
                                   dataInit: function (element) {
                                      $(element).datepicker({          
                 format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                      });
                                   },
                                   
                               },
                           },
                           
                            { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150},
                           { label: 'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 200},
                           {
                            label :'Row Data',
                               name: 'RowData',
                               align : 'center',
                               formatter: function () {
                                   return "<img src='resources/icon.jpg' onclick='OpenDialog(this)' alt='Data Row' />";
                                   width = 15;
                               }
                           },
                       ],
    onSelectRow: editRow, 
    viewrecords: true,
    editurl : "JqGridServlet",
                width: 780,
                height: 200,
                rowNum: 20,
    rowList : [20,30,50],
                rownumbers: true, 
                rownumWidth: 25, 
                multiselect: true,
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
                 loadComplete: function () {
                     var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i;
                     for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                         $this.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i]);
                     }
                    
                 }
            });
            $('#jqGrid').navGrid("#jqGridPager", {
             edit: false, 
             add: true, 
             del: false, 
             refresh: true, 
             view: false
             });
            
        });
```

and here is a screenshoot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1N1W.png)

anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug with the date picker A work around would be to add this to your css.

```
#ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }
```

OR add this to datepicker

```
 $(element).datepicker({    
 autoOpen: false,         
 format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
});
```